# How extract data from a datatable by making comparison between columns (based on certain conditions) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, row, multiple-columns

I have RM process which involves 'FP Growth' operator->'Apply Association Rules' operator. Data Table 1 is the output of that RM process.

Now, i want to write an R program with Data Table 1 as input and Data Table 2 as output

Data Table 1

```
 id confidence(a)   a   confidence(b)   b
100   1           TRUE        1        FALSE
101   0           TRUE        0        FALSE
102   1           TRUE        1        TRUE
103   0           TRUE        0        TRUE
```

Data Table 2

```
 ID  SET
100   b
101  none
102  none
103  none
```

Here's is the logic to get Data Table 2 table -

1. for a particular id,when confidence(a/b/anything) =0 , ignore them
2. for a particular id, when 'confidence(a)' is 1 and value of item 'a' is 'TRUE' -> ignore them
3. for a particular id, when 'confidence(a)' is 1 and value of 'a' is 'FALSE' -> mention this in the 'SET' column (as shown in Data Table 2)
4. so when confidence() = 1 and item value = FALSE all the items with this data should be stored to 'SET' column where each item is separated by comma

Please let me know how can i get Data Table 2. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your Data Table 1 as `dt1`:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(id=100:103, confidencea=c(1,0,1,0), a=rep(T,4), confidenceb=c(1,0,1,0), b=c(F,F,T,T))

str(dt1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id         : int  100 101 102 103
 $ confidencea: num  1 0 1 0
 $ a          : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ confidenceb: num  1 0 1 0
 $ b          : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

#For the code below to work, the columns of dt1 must be in the format above. 
#If not, convert them to the correct format.
#For example, if 'id' is in the format 'factor', use 'as.integer(as.character(dt1$id))'.
#For example, if 'a' is in the format 'character', use 'as.logical(dt1$a)'.
```

Then the code below creates `dt2`:

```
#Find columns where confidence is non-zero
dt <- dt1[which(rowSums(dt1[grep('confidence', names(dt1))]) > 0),]

#Find columns where value of item corresponding to a non-zero confidence is FALSE
dtnames <- names(which(colSums(dt[grep('^(?!confidence|id)', names(dt), perl = T)]) < nrow(dt[grep('^(?!confidence|id)', names(dt), perl = T)])))
dt <- dt[,c(1, which(names(dt) %in% dtnames))]
dt <- dt[which(rowSums(dt[-1]) < (ncol(dt)-1)),]

#Collect names to be listed in SET column
dt$SET <- 'none'
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  name <- character()
  for(j in 2:ncol(dt)){
    if(dt[i,j]==F){
      name <- c(name, names(dt[j]))
    }
  }
  dt$SET[i] <- paste(name, collapse=',')
}

#Keep only SET column and fill missing values with 'none'
dt <- dt[c('id','SET')]
dt2 <- merge(dt1[1],dt, all.x = T)
dt2$SET[is.na(dt2$SET)] <- 'none'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in confidence(a),confidence(b) - a,b are files. In similar way i have many more files as, confidence(c), confidence(d) .... . Please let me know an another to resolve this.

Comment: I modified the code to be more generic. Now it should work regardless of how many columns you have.

Comment: 'x must be numeric' error is diplayed at 4th code line

Comment: you can change the format of any variable in a dataframe to be numeric by using the command `dt$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(dt$variable)`

Comment: #Find columns where value of item corresponding to a non-zero confidence is FALSE -> can you explain this code

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, 'x must be numeric' error is diplayed at 4th code line. Kindly let me know if you received the same error and how did you resolve it.

Comment: I don't get the same error. It seems the problem is that the columns in your original dataframe (dt1) are not in the appropriate format. I've modified my code above to display the format dt1 is in for me. In your case, you can use the `str(dt1)` command to check the format of your columns, and change as necessary using the commands `as.numeric`, `as.integer`, or `as.logical` as necessary.

Comment: As for 'Find columns where value of item corresponding to is non-zero is FALSE':

1. The first line finds where the column sums are less that the number of columns. In R TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0. So if there is a FALSE in a column, its sum will be less than the number of rows. 

2. The second line creates a dataframe with just id and the columns which contain FALSE.

3. The third line removes rows where there is a TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem is to transform the first data frame (hereby named `df1`) from wide to long format using `tidyr::gather` and then operate on the resulting key and value data columns (grouped by `id`) in row pair-wise fashion to evaluate what needs to be in the resulting `SET`. Then, `summarise` using a function to collapse the rows to a string (character vector). For this approach to work, we must have alternating confidence and corresponding item columns as in the OP.

We first define two functions:

```
f <- function(k, v) {
  o <- rep(NA,length(v))
  o[c(FALSE,TRUE)] <- ifelse(v[c(TRUE,FALSE)]==1 & v[c(FALSE,TRUE)]==0, k[c(FALSE,TRUE)], NA)
  o
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)  
  if (length(x)==0) "none" else toString(x)
}
```

The first function operates in the long format columns in pair-wise fashion to generate either `(NA, NA)` or `(NA, item)` for each pair of rows based on the condition. The second function removes all `NA` and then collapses the row to a comma separated string. If all elements in the row are `NA`, then this function returns `"none"` as requested. With these functions, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% gather(key="key", value="Set", -id) %>%
               group_by(id) %>% 
               mutate(Set=f(key,Set)) %>% 
               select(-key) %>%
               summarise(Set=f2(Set))
```

On your data:

```
print(df2)
### A tibble: 4 x 2
##     id   Set
##  <int> <chr>
##1   100     b
##2   101  none
##3   102  none
##4   103  none
```

Now for a slightly more interesting data set with more than one item that satisfies the condition:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 100:103, `confidence(a)` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), a = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), `confidence(b)` = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L), b = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), `confidence(c)` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), c = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("id", 
"confidence(a)", "a", "confidence(b)", "b", "confidence(c)", 
"c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
##   id confidence(a)    a confidence(b)     b confidence(c)     c
##1 100             1 TRUE             1 FALSE             1 FALSE
##2 101             0 TRUE             0 FALSE             0  TRUE
##3 102             1 TRUE             1  TRUE             1 FALSE
##4 103             0 TRUE             0  TRUE             0 FALSE
```

We get:

```
print(df2)
### A tibble: 4 x 2
##     id   Set
##  <int> <chr>
##1   100  b, c
##2   101  none
##3   102     c
##4   103  none
```

Answer (score -1):

It might not be the best way to do this. But, it can be done using simple ifelse() and for loop. Following code can do the required for the given example. You may need to modify it according to your requirement.

```
# Explaining Variables
id = c(100,101,102,103)
confidence_a = c(1,0,1,0)
a = c(TRUE ,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
confidence_b = c(1,0,1,0)
b = c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)

# Create Dataframe using above declared variables
Data_Table_1 =  data.frame(id, confidence_a,a,confidence_b , b)
colnames(Data_Table_1) = c("id" , "confidence_a" , "a" , "confidence_b"      ,"b")

# Defining Null Vectors
SET = c()
SET_a = c()
SET_b = c()
# Loop to iterate over each of the row 
for( i in 1:nrow(Data_Table_1)){

      SET_a[i] =  ifelse((Data_Table_1$confidence_a[i] == 0),"none",
                    ifelse((Data_Table_1$confidence_b[i] == 0),"none",
                        ifelse(Data_Table_1[i ,3] == "FALSE" ,colnames(Data_Table_1)[3],"none")))

            SET_b[i] =  ifelse((Data_Table_1$confidence_a[i] == 0),"none",
                            ifelse((Data_Table_1$confidence_b[i] == 0),"none",
                                ifelse(Data_Table_1[i ,5] == "FALSE" ,colnames(Data_Table_1)[5],"none")))

                    SET[i]   = ifelse((SET_a[i] != "none")&(SET_b[i]!= "none") ,paste(SET_a[i] ,SET_b[i],sep = "," ), 
                                   ifelse(SET_a[i] != "none",SET_a[i] ,
                                       ifelse(SET_b[i] !="none", SET_b[i],"none")))}
```

You can optimize given code adding more loop over columns.